# How do I get the index of a certain element in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm learning about `ArrayList`s and I was wondering, how do you get the index of a certain element in an `ArrayList`?

I know you can use `myArray.contains("string")`, but how can I find the index of the element without doing something like `myArray.get()`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object) In general, you should look at the API of the class before asking a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Foo element = //...
ArrayList<Foo> list = //...
int index = list.indexOf(element) // retrieve index of element - first occurrence
```

**Example:**

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)).indexOf(3); // returns 2
```

The index works the same as indexes of an array (first element has index 0, second element has 1, etc.). For more about this method, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-

This also works with any implementation of `java.util.List`, and, if you want the last occurrence, use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.Object-

Using the above example, `lastIndexOf()` works differently:

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)).lastIndexOf(3);
// returns 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [`ArrayList#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-).....